# Default unit of key buffer size

Tags: mysql

I run a query in mysql

```
 SELECT @@key_buffer_size as keybufsize;
```

to check my key buffer size i got a value which is 8388608. There is no K or M or anything after that. What is this memory  unit? Is it a Byte, Bit or anything else

Comment: The value is in bytes, your key buffer size is `8 MB`

Comment: Why do you want to use myisam in the first place?

Comment: just taking a look on performance